# Getting undefined value in JS variable in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, lightning-web-components

I have a apex class which is having one method with returntype wrapper class. i am binding the return type in helper in a response attribute (type is object). I want to fetch two variables i.e. id,status from response.
Currently I am getting undefined error in output.

**Reponse attribute in cmp:**

<aura:attribute name="response" type="object"/>

**Helper.js:**

({
getStatusHelper : function(component, event,helper) {

```
    var jobID = event.getParam("Pass_Result");
    component.set("v.jobId", jobID);
    var action = component.get("c.getCalloutResponseStatus");
    
    action.setParams({"jobId": jobID});
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
           
           component.set("v.response", response.getReturnValue());
            **var getStatus = component.get("v.response").status; //GETTING UNDEFINED ERROR
            var getJobId = component.get("v.response").id; //GETTING UNDEFINED ERROR**
            
        }
        else{
            alert('Failed status call from child!!');
        }

});
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

can anyone pls help me on this issue.

Comment: It look Like problem problem in "id". JS is case-sensitive. try using "Id" var getJobId = component.get("v.response").Id; //GETTING UNDEFINED ERROR** Also, check other field also.

Comment: We would need to see your Apex code. This should only be a problem if you were returning a null value for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your wrapper class is public and has the @AuraEnabled notation in its variables, as well as they are public with get;set; example:

```
public class wrapperClass{
    @AuraEnabled public List<contact> lstContact{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public Integer contactCount{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled public String headerMsg {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Hi, All of them is already in place

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
           const result = response.getReturnValue();
           component.set("v.response", result);
           let getStatus = result.status; //make sure it is not Status
           let getJobId = result.id; ////make sure it is not Id
}
```